# ¿Cómo iniciar ventana modal automáticamente al cargar la página?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy usando un login de bootstrap pero cada que se quiere iniciar sesion pide dar click en una liga y despues entrar a la forma del login. Yo quisiera quitar esa parte y que desde un inicio se mire la forma de iniciar sesion.

Esto es lo que se muestra en un inicio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito quitar esa parte y que desde un inicio se muestre el login.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el codigo html.

```
<html>
       <body>           
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#myModal" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal">Click to Open Login Modal</a>
            </div>   

        <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign In</button>
                            </div>
                            <p class="hint-text"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">Don't have an account? <a href="#">Create one</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo debes indicarle que abra el modal al terminar de cargar la pagina. Puedes agregar:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
});
```

Mas allá de esto, te recomiendo dejar un botón para lanzar el modal, ya que si el usuario cierra accidentalmente el mismo, va a tener que recargar la pagina para poder acceder. Saludos!

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="text-center">
                <a href="#myModal" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal">Click to Open Login Modal</a>
            </div>   

        <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign In</button>
                            </div>
                            <p class="hint-text"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">Don't have an account? <a href="#">Create one</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```